# kubernetes pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

The server have those docker images.[the red is pulled from repository,the yellow were modified by myself,and then commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etv3I.jpg)

now,i use the images which pulled  from  repository to create pod,it's no error,and running.
`apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: sds
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: sds
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sds
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: sds
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         image: tomcat
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080`
[the red pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRZKE.jpg)

but if I use the images which I modified to create pod,it's crachLoopBackOff.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: sds
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: sds
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sds
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: sds
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         image: mytomcat
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080`
[the red one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oqBE.jpg)

I use `kubectl logs [podname]`，but show nothing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaqbh.jpg)
i use `kubectl describe pod [podName]` show the describe of this pod !
[the describe of the error pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/742MI.jpg)

Comment: Try starting the docker container without Kubernetes.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what did you modify to generate your custom image?

Comment: only cop a war to the webapps of tomcat,if I starting the docker container without kubernetes ,it's working.

Answer (score 0):

A CrashLoopBackOff can have different causes:
- your container finishes very quickly and since you have 1 replica, Kubernetes restarts it again and again....
- your container doesn't have correct permissions on a volume

It depends on what kind of changes you made on your docker image.

Comment: only cop a war to the webapps of tomcat.you say that my container doesn't have permission on a volume.But how to make my container hava the correct permission on a volume?